# Spring AOP with Generics : AfterReturning Twice

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-aop

I am trying to intercept a function save in order to make a history entry of it but the aspect is being invoked twice.

I will show you the code first and then explain to you my debug analysis afterwards...

So i got a FunctionServiceSupport which is defined as follows :

```
@Named
@Qualifier("functionService")
public class FonctionServiceSupport extends BaseServiceSupport<FunctionDTO, Function> {}

public abstract class BaseServiceSupport<T extends BaseDTO, E extends BaseEntity> implements BaseService<T> {
    @Inject
    protected BaseRepository<E> baseRepository;
    @Inject
    protected BaseMapper<T, E> mapper;

    @Override
    public T save(T dto) {
        E entity = mapper.dtoToEntity(dto);
        entity = baseRepository.save(entity);
        return mapper.entityToDto(entity);
    }
}
```

My DTO :

```
public class FunctionDTO extends BaseDTO {}
public abstract class BaseDTO {}
```

and then my aspect :

```
    @Aspect
    @Named
    public class HistoryFunctionServiceSupport extends HistoryBaseServiceSupport<FunctionDTO, FunctionHistory> {
        @Override
        @AfterReturning(
            pointcut="execution(* x.y.z.services.BaseService+.save(*))",
            returning="dto")
        public void addNewHistorisyEntry(FunctionDTO dto) {
            super.addNewHistorisyEntry(dto);
        }
    }

public abstract class HistoryBaseServiceSupport<D extends BaseDTO, E extends BaseEntityHistory> implements HistoryBaseService<D> {
    @Inject
    protected BaseHistoryMapper<E, D> historyMapper;
    @Inject
    protected BaseHistoryRepository<E> historyRepository;

    @Override
    public void addNewHistorisyEntry(D dto) {
        E historyEntity = historyMapper.entityDtoToEntityHistory(dto);
        historyRepository.save(historyEntity);
    }
}
```

So running the save method on FunctionServiceSupport cause the @AfterReturning advice to be called twice.

After some debug of `org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAdvisorChainFactory.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice()`

the `method` parameter gets the value :

```
public abstract x.y.z.dto.BaseDTO x.y.z.services.BaseService.save(x.y.z.dto.BaseDTO)
```

`targetClass` parameter : `class x.y.z.services.FunctionServiceSupport`

And generates two advice interceptors :

```
[
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor@7f31e4ab,
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor@2a5fd98f,
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor@7ac45104
]
```

The first AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor is detailed as follows :

```
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterReturningAdvice:
advice method [
public void x.y.z.services.HistoryFunctionServiceSupport.addNewHistoryEntry(x.y.z.dto.BaseDTO)];
aspect name 'historyFunctionServiceSupport'
```

And the second one which is :

```
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterReturningAdvice:
advice method [
public void x.y.z.services.HistoryFunctionServiceSupport.addNewHistoryEntry(x.y.z.dto.FunctionDTO)];
aspect name 'historyFunctionServiceSupport'
```

I see that it generated two Advice Interceptors one with `FunctionDTO` which seems to be totally fine.
But the other one with `BaseDTO`, which is an abstract class, and i think it's the one causing the double execution....

Did i go too far and just missing a simple configuration somewhere?